# invalid object name 'dbo.Table' - EntityFramework 4.1

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I keep getting this error when i run my MVC application. The app builds fine but throws this error on the runtime.

Here is the scenario.

```
[DisplayColumn("Name", "Name", false)]
public partial class ApplicationAction
{
    public Guid ApplicationActionId { get; set; } 
    [Required, StringLength(150), Column("ActionName")]
    public string Action { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(150)]
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Area { get; set; }
    [StringLength(250)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    //Navigation Properties
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationActionGroup> ApplicationActionGroups { get; set; }

    public ApplicationAction()
    {
        ApplicationActionId = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
public DbSet<ApplicationAction> ApplicationActions { get; set; }

public static ApplicationAction GetAction(string actionName, string controller, string area, IEnumerable<ApplicationAction> actions)
    {
        foreach (ApplicationAction a in actions)
        {
            if (a.Action.Equals(actionName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                && a.Controller.Equals(controller, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                && (
                    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Area) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(area)) ||
                    (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Area) && a.Area.Equals(area, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                   )
                )
            {
                return a;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I get an error on GetAction method. It comes up as Invalid object name 'dbo.ApplicationAction'. The sql database, there is a table called ApplicationActions. Not sure whats causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that [DisplayColumn("Name", "Name", false)]
is a valid attribute for a class?

Comment: Sorry, this was solved..it had to do with the plural names of the object. The table in the database had "s" in it, while the object was singular. So, it couldn't find the dbo.table..this was fixed. Thanks for your reply.